# Black Box Optimization

Tags: optimization

I want to find the maximum possible value of an unknown function on a rectangle. What is the optimal method of doing this? Do I need to use simulated annealing?

Comment: What is your input? What is your output? Your question is too vague to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more details, as indicated in the comment above.  It's not clear what information you have:  If the function is unknown, it seems like you have no information to let you find any solution, so it's not clear what you are asking.  It's not clear how you will evaluate answers.  What approaches have you already considered?  What criteria will you use for evaluating possible solutions?  "optimal" by what metric?